# How does defining prototypes for copy constructor in private section of class prevents copying of class?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

How does defining prototypes for copy constructor in private section of class prevents copying of class in C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, member functions which are in the `private` section of a class can only be called by other member functions of the same class. (Similarly, `protected` members can be called by derived classes, and `public` members can be called by anyone.)

In order to copy an object, you need a copy constructor. If you don't write your own, then the compiler will supply one for you. But if you *do* write your own, then the usual access rules will apply. So if you put the definition of the copy constructor in the `private` section of your class, then the compiler will see that there is a constructor with the right signature (so it won't provide you with one), but then complain that it can't call it because it's private.

Back in the old C++98 days, this was the usual way to prevent copying of a class. C++11 has a better approach: you say

```
struct MyType
{
    MyType(const MyType&) = delete;
};
```

to explicitly say to the compiler "I am not providing this function, and do not generate it function for me". This has the same effect as defining a private copy constructor, but provides a better error message to anyone attempting to copy the class.

Comment: In addition (for C++98 way), if copy is used by the class, you get a link error as there is only declaration and no definition.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you pass a non temporary object or an object with value it tries to use an *accessible* copy constructor to create object. Once its *explicitly deleted<sub>**[C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor)**</sub>* or put in private/protected section, access from outside is not possible leading to an error at compile time, hence making you aware that copying is not possible.

Such class are not *Copy-Construtible* .